# How can I change Swingworker to AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

How can I change Swingworker to  AsyncTask in Android?

My code is as follows.

```
private void showWeather() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<WeatherInfo,Object>()
         {
             public WeatherInfo doInBackground()
             {
                 YahooWeather yahooWeather = new YahooWeather();
                 return yahooWeather.getWeatherInfo();
             }
             public void done()
             {
                 try {
                      WeatherInfo wInfo = get();   // get WeatherInfo result from background thread
                      updateGUI(wInfo);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){} 
             }
         };
         worker.execute();
    }
```

Comment: it have error at  SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<WeatherInfo,Object>()

Comment: "and it have error at get();" isn't very helpful. Is it a compilation error? Do you get an Exception at runtime? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead

Comment: @Chio Oho `AsyncFlag` IS a `SwingWorker` for Android, it just a different class name. The logic behind is exactly the same. Why would you need a `SwingWorker`?

Comment: hmm that code when i run in java application it is ok. but when i put that code on eclipse it have error. So i will confuse about Swingworker. Can you edit the code above?

Comment: @Chio Oho android application is not actually a java application and is not a swing application for sure. So you have to stick to android framework. Take a look at the doc please, I'm sure you'll figure out how `AsyncTask` works - the logic is the same, even the method names are similar